# Need to combine .getElementsByClass and .getElementsById to scrape data from website

Tags: excel, web, web-scraping, scrape, vba

I am writing a simple crawler using VBA. I found out that the data I am looking for correspond to the node `<h6 class="country-name" id="Australia">`.

I know that if I wanted to select data from, let us say, `<div class="section-country">`, I should use `.getElementsByClassName("section-country")` in my VBA macro.

In presence of both class **and** id in the node, which command should I insert in my VBA macro to scrape data?

Thanks a lot,
Avitus

EDIT: writing .getElementsByClassName("country-name").getElementsById("Australia") gives me an error. Why?

Comment: I would recommend use id selector as its normally unique instead of class which is generally used at many places in the html.

Comment: So would you just write  .getElementsById("Australia") to select the data in the node  <h6 class="country-name" id="Australia">?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByID` (plural) doesn't exist - there should only be one item with a given ID. Therefore, use `getElementByID` (singular) which does exist. If there happen to be multiple elements with the same ID, this function will return the first one.

As others have said, selecting by ID sounds more appropriate to what you want to do than selecting by class

Comment: I see, so Id is more specific than class, in a certain sense. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There must be a method like getelementbyxpath you can use this method by using this xpath "//div[@class='country-name' and @id ='Australia']"

eg: getElementsByXpath("//div[@class='country-name' and @id ='Australia']")

Read More here [how to set up a crawler for web scraping](https://www.promptcloud.com/extract-data-from-a-website-extract-data-from-multiple-sites/)